# Get the JS name of a field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

im doing some modifications to a Wordpress theme. I dont have too much knowledge in Javascript, but i need to change the data showed on a data table, but i dont know how to get a correct ID for specific fields of my Theme.

```
t._v(" "),
n("td", { staticClass: "mh-table-my-properties__td-created" }, [t._v(t._s(e.item.**codigo**))]),
```

I need to know the " Javascript ID " of the "Codigo" field on my theme. If you need more information comment it, thanks.

Comment: that code is compiled and minified by vuejs/babel how do you want to change it without breaking something

Comment: I have unminified it

Comment: this exmple code looks minifed, i guess it is minifed isnt it?

Comment: Its vue, but its unminified with unminify.com

Comment: well unminifying vue isnt that easy i guess. if you write vuejs apps you usually have for example components `<template>...</template>` and this templates gets compiled to javascript so that vue.js render function can render it. the problem with unminify is that you get that compiled javascript code instead of `<template>...</template>`